# Updating selected value of a dropdown list with jQuery in PyroCMS

Tags: javascript, select, jquery-chosen, pyrocms

I am facing a little problem in the development of a module for **PyroCMS**.

I want to update a dropdown list dynamically using jQuery.
I would like to set the selected option, but it does not seem to work since the dropdown list is not the default one of the browser.

I tried this :

```
$('select[name=item-type] option[value='+type+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but the UI isn't updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The dropdown custom UI is powered by a plugin called [**Chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen).

Editing the DOM element does not update the *Chosen dropdown UI* because this plugin does not dynamically spy on its attached `<select>`. You need to tell explicitely Chosen that you have just updated the DOM by firing an event.

Until version `2.3` PyroCMS uses Chosen `0.9`, so you may trigger the event like that:

```
$('select.any-selector').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

---

To be complete, with Chosen `1.0` the event has changed, and you must use:

```
$("select.any-selector").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

---

References:

- https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/19059
- Chosen website: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
- Chosen Github repo: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
- PyroCMS plugin.js on Github [system/cms/themes/pyrocms/js/plugins.js](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.3/develop/system/cms/themes/pyrocms/js/plugins.js#L331)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution

Two changes required

use

```
$('.selector').chosen().change(function() { 
});
```

instead of

```
$('.selector').change(function() { 
});
```

and when you want to update a dropdown use

```
$('.selector').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

and here you go ...
have fun !!!